# how to replace a particular pattern by the values of other file?

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed

I have a sample file which is having content like given below.I want to replace the value CP[0-9]* for each line with the value from a differnt file. The original file have some space as well after the values in each line and i need to keep them as well.

Original File Sample;

```
05CP14159170891652517

05CP14159170891652522

05CP14159170891652515

05CP14159212891662119

05CP14160021691687657

05CP14159064591626228

05CP14159064591626229
```

File which file be used for replacement:

```
DBB126EEEE
DBB131EEEE
DBB140EEEE
DBB145EEEE
DBB146EEEE
DBB147EEEE
DBB159EEEE
DBB171EEEE
```

I want to replace say for e.g   05CP14159170891652517  with    DBB126EEEE and 05CP14159170891652522 with DBB131EEEE and so on.

Please suggest me how it could be done.

Comment: you mean replacing the whole line or only after 05?

Comment: only after 05 and space at end should remain in new file.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC there is no easy way to do this with `sed`, `awk` on the other can do this fairly straightforwardly:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { repl[FNR] = $0; next } NF { sub("05.*", "05" repl[++i]) } 1' replfile origfile
```

Output:

```
05DBB126EEEE

05DBB131EEEE

05DBB140EEEE

05DBB145EEEE

05DBB146EEEE

05DBB147EEEE

05DBB159EEEE
```

The script loads replacement strings into the `repl` array and then uses the array to do the replacements with `sub()`.

Comment: Thanks Thor but using this way i need to write the values in other new file correct? And also i was not able to keep the space which i mentioned in question that after each line there are some spaces which i need to keep in new file as well.

Comment: @GauravParek: Unless you are exclusively replacing bytes, you always have to write a new file, some programs do this for you behind the scenes, e.g. `sed -i`, but a new file is written nonetheless. With regards to the preservation of space, I thought you meant preserve the double line-spacing. In order to make it clearer you should add the desired output to the question.

Comment: I am sorry if it caused confusion.Now i think you have understood my doubt, could you please help me whether this can be done or not. Thanks in advance

Comment: @GauravParek: I still do not see what is missing from this answer. Can you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24156677/edit) and include exactly the output you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the output with the below command

```
awk 'FNR==NR { repl[FNR] = $0; next } { sub("05.*", "05" repl[++i]) } 1' replfile origfile
```

@Thor: what would be the use of NF in between the loops?

I was unable to comment since i dint have 50+ reputations.

Comment: Each awk code block has a boolean expression attached to it, that determines if it should be executed or not. `NF` in this case ensures that `{ sub("05.*", "05" repl[++i]) }` is only executed when the line contains any fields. A more correct expression, now that I think about it, would be `/^05/`.